# Wordpress: Showing the gravatar profile while clicking on the profile picture

Tags: wordpress, gravatar

I have a blog, created with wordpress, and I am using the theme twenty fourteen. There is a contributor page template, where you can add your profile picture via gravatar. That's what I did, and that's what's working so far.

In the demo version of the theme (https://twentyfourteendemo.wordpress.com/default-page-templates/contributor-page-template/) it's seen that the whole gravatar profile is shown while clicking on the profile picture in the wordpress blog. I would like to do the same, but I couldn't find out how to do it.

Can anybody help me?
Thank you!

Greetings,
pradhana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to Add Gravatar Hovercards to your Blog or Site?**

https://en.gravatar.com/support/profile-hovercards/